# Click to call button from browser to phone

Tags: twilio-click-to-call

I have requirement where i need to have a "Talk to Sales" button on my website. The user would be able to talk to sales or the support team by clicking the "Talk to Sales" button.
I have tried a lot of cloud telephonic solutions like knowlarity and Twilio, but the solution which they gave me :

The user will have to enter there phone number and then the call would get connected between the user and the agent.
I have two problems with this solution :

```
1) The user's are very reluctant to give their phone numbers the first time they visit the website.
2) The solution is not cheap. In this i will have to pay for 2 calls : call to user and call to the agent.
```

So i need a solution which is cheap and does not require the user to enter his phone number.
Is there any solution wherein they click the "Talk to Sales" button and then the user would be able to talk through browser connected to sales/support guy on the phone?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to write a little code.

- Use twilio's javascript API to setup a call button in your website.
  (Refer [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/client))
- Dial the Sales number when a user clicks on the button.

In this solution, the user doesn't need to provide any info. They can just click the button and start talking. The call cost of browser to twilio calls are pretty cheap. So you can cut the cost in this leg.

(Please note that since twilio js api relies on webrtc, your website should have an ssl certificate installed (https website) for this to work in all browsers. Chrome blocks webrtc from non-ssl sites)